# CHAR_HEX_CONVERSION results in ABAP dump

Tags: types, char, hex, abap

I need to convert a char (`char20` to be specific) into a HEX value. I came up with the following:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'CHAR_HEX_CONVERSION'
  EXPORTING
    input     = character
  IMPORTING
    hexstring = character_hex.
```

However I always get an runtime error when doing this.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which runtime error exactly ?

Comment: UC_OBJECTS_NOT_CHAR

However the variable "character" is declared as a char20... really weird

Comment: What value are you passing in parameter `INPUT`? What are the types of your input and output parameters?

Comment: It's from the calling function and it's a CHAR20 which most of the time only contains a single character.

Comment: Please consider adding a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question. This will improve your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested `CHAR_HEX_CONVERSION` and I get what I think is the same dump:

> For the statement    "WRITE src TO dest" only flat, character-type
>   data objects are supported at the argument position "dest".
>
> In this case, the operand "dest" has the non-character-type or
>   non-flat type "X". The current program is a Unicode program. In the
>   Unicode context, the type 'X' or structures containing not only
>   character-type components are regarded as non-character-type.

I think it's the use of an `X` type that's causing the dump. I've not found another released function module that can do the conversion (coding it by hand is easy enough, but I'm lazy!), but I can suggest the following function module instead: `CRM_EI_KB_CONV_DEC_TO_HEX`. Despite the name it's available in an ECC 6.0 system and should do what you need.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! I'll try to get it working with that and as soon as it works, will mark your answer as correct (By the way that's the same dump)

Comment: This function module will convert a **decimal number** to its equivalent hex value (255 --> 0xFF), **not** an arbitrary character to its hex value ('A' --> 0x41 or whatever, depending on the encoding).

Comment: @vwegert Ah yes, good point - I'd missed the point that the OP wanted to convert an arbitrary character to hex.

Comment: Actually I didn't want to convert an arbitrary character so your answer is correct, thank you very much! Should've written that. Sorry I can't mark both answers as correct but I'm sure it'll help other users from Google!

Answer (score 2):

The dump happens when passing the incomming value to a fieldsymbol, which refers to the exporting parameter. In the code it is an assign statement with type 'X' added afterwards, which I usually not recommend this way.

I also made a used-where check on this module and it's function group and it seems as if it is nowhere invoked, at least not directly. Very likely, that the entire function group was never released.

Comment: First, thanks for helping! So this does mean that I'll have to use a different function/make my own function, right ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the `SCMS` function modules instead - they also take care of code-page conversions. Try `SCMS_TEXT_TO_BIN` or `SCMS_STRING_TO_XSTRING`.

Comment: Wouldn't be very convenient since I need to use the BIT-XOR Operator afterwards which only takes hexadecimals. But thank you anyways!

Comment: Is "convenient" more important than "correct"? And at least on the system I have in front of me, `BIT-XOR` is perfectly capable of handling `XSTRING`s.

Comment: Oh no, I'm sorry, I just overread the 'x' in front of the string. Now it sounds good! Definetly going to try that.